# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: kubernetes, node-red

I am running node-red on kubernetes locally. This is my deployment code:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nodered
  name: nodered
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodered
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodered
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodered
        image: nodered/node-red:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: "0.2"
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: "1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1880
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nodered-claim
          mountPath: /data/nodered
          # subPath: nodered <-- not needed in your case
      volumes:
      - name: nodered-claim
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nodered-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: small-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - minikube
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nodered-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node-red-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nodered
  ports:
    - port: 1880
      targetPort: 1880
```

I am trying to feed a local text file in my directory into node red but I am getting the error - ""Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\SHRDC\abss\test.txt'"

[image]

What could be a solution to this?

I have tried \data\test.txt but that hasn't worked either. I am expecting nodered to read the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know is that under most situations is that kubernetes pods run docker containers that are Linux based. This means that even if you are running your kubernetes node on a Windows machine it will be running in a Linux virtual machine. This means 2 things.

1. All paths used will need to use the Unix style
2. it will have no direct access to files on the host Windows machine

Next while you have requested a volume to be mounted into the pod at `/data/nodered` and defined both a physical volume and a physical volume claim (which I'm not sure will actually map to each other in this case) they will be in the Linux Virtual machine not the urgently Windows machine so will not have access to files on the host.

Even if you had managed to copy the file into the directory that is backing the volume mount in the pod the correct path to give to Node-RED would be something like `/data/nodered/test.txt` based on the volume mount